# Can not generate scenario with AND word

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, specflow, behavior

I have a problem with generate scenario in Specflow, with AND word

Scenario contains `And` phrase, but after Generate Step Definition Skeleton it change to `When`.

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/6riSQ.png]

Comment: I made mistake in description, it change to "Given" not "When"

Answer (score 1):

The (auto steps generator) *SpecFlow* detects that the **first two sentences are the same**, except the numbers that are considers parameters. Try to add the word "first" to the first sentence and the word "second" to the second sentence and re*generate the step definition*. Actually you can add any word that differentiate the first sentence from the second.:

```
Scenario: Add two numbers
    Given I have entered first 50 into the calculator
    And I have entered second 70 into the calculator
    When I press add
    Then the result should be 120 on the screen
```

You will get a **new step** but you won't see the `And` attribute in the steps. It looks like `StepDefinitionBaseAttribute` (which is implemented by `WhenAttribute`) has no `And` attribute implemented and the use of it is only in the Gherkin file for readability.

Note that *Specflow* doesn't care whether you name a step `Given`, `When` or `Then` but it should match an expression in the steps and used for readability. **The order does matter**.

Answer (score 0):

Its all absolutely correct. Specflow is a BDD approach that uses keywords: `GIVEN, WHEN, THEN.`

When your `GIVEN` condition is more complex (more steps) you can use `AND` keyword but still step itself is `GIVEN` one. Thanks to that you can use same steps in multiple tests and chains as long as `GIVEN`, `WHEN`, `THEN` keyword fits.

Furthermore, if you want to have one step definition used in multiple keywords you can mark that step with attribute of `GIVEN`, `WHEN`, `THEN` at the same time to avoid code repetition.

Also Specflow lets you pass parameters from feature file into step definition. So you could merge first two steps in one.